# How the state will store the data in redux in react native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-redux

I would like to know that
if we are storing the data in a state in redux,
and suddenly the data is updated to redux
will the previous state will be overidden
or will it maintain a copy or like versions (v1,v2)
can anyone please guide me on this?

Comment: It will not maintain the copy its like database when you update its overwritten, however if you want to maintain the copy you can use `redux-logger`.

Answer (score 1):

The previous states will not be stored, once you close the app the "session" is cleared, minimizing the app will see the state persists, there are a number of options for permanent data storage, redux-persist is one of them, and probably the easiest to implement, there is also a built in option with react-native (this is however the worst option as i find it often causes my apps to hang if a process takes too long, i suspect it's blocking the js thread). The best option, but slightly more difficult to setup is https://realm.io/ which i use in conjunction with redux and saga, this is great for an offline first approach to building your app, as you can check users connectivity and either make calls to your api, or to your realm storage.

See code example below for appending data in reducer and replacing data:

```
  case NEXT_PAGE_SUCCESS:
      return {
        ...state,
        busy: false,
        msg: action.payload.statusText,
        status: true,
        data: [...state.data, ...action.payload.data]
      }
```

In the above reducer case, ...state will drop in the previous state, now afterwards we also assign busy: false, this will overwrite the old busy state.

Now if you look at the data field, we have:

```
[...state.data,...action.payload.data]
```

This will combine the previous state.data, with the new state.data appending the list instead of overwriting.

I hope this answers your question?

Lloyd

Comment: Thanks for your answer.but,I am not trying to close the app or minimise it.I am just trying to update the state in reducer. my app gets the 20mb of data to the reducer and store in a state.what happens if I additionally get 10 mb of data and update the state.so,whether the previous state will get override or it will create a new memory.if it gets override then how can we get previous state.If any logic misses,forgive me.I am just trying to clear my doubt.

Comment: This will depend on how you setup your reducer. So if you are fetching a list of items, and you grab the first 10, then you would like to grab the next 10, you can setup your reducer so that it appends the existing list of items or replaces them, ill include a code example above.